# How to change the text color and background of the menu item

Tags: xamarin.android

I make a menu according to this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGO-xcpJUBs

How to change the text color and background of the menu item?

my files:

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style  name="MyStyle"
          parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
  </style>
</resources>
```

2.menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu tools.context=".MainActivity"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:title="@string/name"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:id="@+id/iname"/>

  <item android:title="@string/email"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:id="@+id/iemail"/>
</menu>
```

adding this line does not give anything:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
```

Comment: Pls put all necessary information in question. No one will watch video to check if he/she can help you. External links although allowed may disappear making whole question useless for future users facing this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Change the background of the menu item

You could add an attribute in your `styles.xml` to change the menu background color :

```
<item name="android:itemBackground">#FFFCF8FA</item>
```

Here is my `styles.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="Theme.MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:itemBackground">#FF8898F1</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

> Change the text color of the menu item

You can implement this feature programmatically, change the color of the `MenuItem` text easily by using `SpannableString` instead of `string`.

Here is my code :

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_form, menu);

    for (int i = 0; i < menu.Size(); i++)
    {
        IMenuItem item = menu.GetItem(i);
        Android.Text.SpannableString spanString = new Android.Text.SpannableString(menu.GetItem(i).ToString());
        spanString.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Android.Graphics.Color.Red), 0, spanString.Length(), 0); //fix the color to red
        item.SetTitle(spanString);
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRopX.png).